# <Data Binding Error>Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am trying to bind the list box with dropdownlist. I want same data of listbox should be store in SQL, but system is giving error. Please help me on this. Here is the code.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="FBGivenByName" 
  DataTextField="EMLOYEE_NAME" DataValueField="EMLOYEE_NAME" Height="24px" 
  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("FbGivenBy_Name") %>'>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: You need to tell us what error you are getting, how your data source look like

Comment: Hi Navakov, iam getting <Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control> error. i have one dropdown list iam linking a list box with dropdown list by using where command in configure data source. but when iam entering somting in dropdownlist then asp.net is showing above error. i want to insert the list box data in the SQL.

Comment: @user3815633, is this ListBox contained within a databound control?

Comment: YES . THIS LIST Box is with databound control

Comment: I want to insert list box display data into sql table

Comment: It is *with* or *within* a databound control? There is a difference.

Comment: so what i need to do. that can insert the data without any error. please help